# how to filter data in kotlin based on item

Tags: kotlin

this is  method where i am getting data month list  but when i try to filter with two filed i am getting compile error

```
  override fun onGraphDataLoaded(data: List<GraphData>?) {
    Log.d("DATAITEM", data?.size.toString())
    var childList: List<GraphData>? = data?.let { it.filter { s -> s.isChild && t -> t.beginningTime>0 } }
    var parentList: List<GraphData>? = data?.let { it.filter { s -> !s.isChild } }
    Log.d("DATAITEM", "ChildSize"+childList?.size)
    Log.d("DATAITEM", "ParentSize"+parentList?.size)

}
```

this is my model class

```
data class GraphData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    var beginningTime: Long? = 0L,
    var endTime: Long? = 0L,
    var isChild: Boolean
)
```

i want to filter data based on ischild and beginningTime>0 but it show compile time error please help me in this .

Comment: You should probably be checking `s -> s.isChild` only, that means do not use the `==`operator when checking `var isChild: Boolean`, because it's a **`Boolean`** that cannot be an `Int` like `1`.

Comment: can you please help me how to filter based on multiple cndition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using both s and t as lambda parameters. You can't change the name of the lambda parameter in the middle of an expression!

Also, you're comparing a nullable property to an int. You need to take care of its nullability.

Thirdly, there's no need for `.let` - that makes the line more complicatted. Just filter directly.

```
var childList = data?.filter { it.isChild && (it.beginningTime ?: 0) > 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the "isChild Boolean variable" with "true" or "false"

```kotlin
override fun onGraphDataLoaded(data: List<GraphData>?) {
   Log.d("DATAITEM", data?.size.toString())
   var monthList: List<GraphData>? = data?.let { it.filter {s->s.isChild ==ntrue
   } 
}
```

Comment: i did but data is not fetching its loading infinitely its seems filtering is not happening

Comment: thanks for help but i have edited question actually i want to filleter based on two parameter

Comment: This works, but `s.isChild` on its own is a valid boolean expression, no `== true` is required. The only place where `== true` would make sense is if you're dealing with a nullable `Boolean?` (which is not the case here). So I would not suggest comparing with `true` explicitly like this.